# How to install turicreate in ubuntu22?

Tags: ubuntu-22.04, turi-create

It had **Python** **3.10.4** installed already and **turicreate** requires **python 3.7**
So how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not already installed pip alongside python, run:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

And after that:

```
pip3 install turicreate
```